# gridview item animation after action drop

Tags: android, animation, gridview

i m new to android and as per requirement implementing drag and drop on gridview to achieve the swap operation all thing working fine and also interchanging the item within the gridview what i had done so far:-
 implement the touchlistner to the imageview in the adapter class

here-

```
holder.disp_imgview.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener(mcontext));
```

holder is the inner class for the adapter class and MyTouchListner class for touch event.

here -

```
public final class MyTouchListener  implements OnTouchListener {

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            vb=(Vibrator) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vb.vibrate(100);
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view_position=view.getId();
            first_image_view=view;

            Log.v("IMAGE TOUCH", "CLICKED");
            return true;
}
```

where `DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder` is creating a shadow for the specific image touched by user and starting the dragging `view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);`

next implement the drag event for the imageview in the adapter class only

here-

```
holder.disp_imgview.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sec_view_id=v.getId();
                 first_view_id=MyTouchListener.view_position;


                switch(event.getAction())
                {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

                    Log.e("ACTION", "DRAG_STARTED");

                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);

                    Log.e("ACTION", "DRAG_ENTERED");
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    Log.e("ACTION", "DRAG_ENTERED");
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                    if(first_view_id!=sec_view_id)
                    {
                        Integer temp=my_image_list.get(first_view_id);
                        Integer temp_sec=my_image_list.get(sec_view_id);
                        my_image_list.set(first_view_id, temp_sec);
                        my_image_list.set(sec_view_id, temp);
                        image_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(mcontext, "CAN'T PLACE THE SAME IMAGE", 0).show();   
                    }
                    Log.e("ACTION", "ACTION_DROP");
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    Log.e("ACTION", "DRAG_ENDED");
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    Log.e("ACTION", "DRAG_EXITED");
                    break;

                }

                return true;
            }

        }
```

as u can see on action drop swapping the image in arraylist (my_image_list) and after that notify the adapter to reflect the change and is working fine but now the question is

How can we do animation on the second item so that it look like it move to the first item position in the gridview and animation will occur after the action drop.

Comment: is this what you wish to achieve :  http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/pageddragdropgrid/ ? have you tried this library?

Comment: in that library how can we increase the row number if the item number exceed the total page height so that it can be scrollable as like gridview of android

Comment: i don't know. i didn't try it out. i only suggested checking it out.

Comment: already tried but that is only the problem if we add item more than the page height than also it is not scrollable,i will go with that again to sees if something can be done.

Comment: ok, i wonder how good this library is anyway. might be handy some day.